# Typescript discriminated unions: Property does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I'm going to use Discriminated Union type for Reducer Action.

But when I use it the compiler says the payload does not contain the property.

The code looks like

```js
interface AuthenticatedUserState {
    user?: any
    isAdmin?: boolean
    isRegistered?: boolean
    err?: any
    isError?: boolean
    isSignedOut?: boolean
    authorizationData?: any
}

const INITIAL_STATE: AuthenticatedUserState = {
    user: null,
    isError: false,
    err: null,
    isSignedOut: false
}

interface AUTHENTICATED_USER_ACTION {
    type: 'authentication/AUTHENTICATED_USER'
    payload: {
        authenticatedUser: any
        isAdmin: boolean
    }
}

interface REGISTER_USER_ACTION {
    type: 'authentication/REGISTER_USER'
    payload: {
        isRegistered: boolean
        err: any
    }
}

const AUTHENTICATED_USER = 'authentication/AUTHENTICATED_USER'
const REGISTER_USER = 'authentication/REGISTER_USER'

type ACTION = AUTHENTICATED_USER_ACTION | REGISTER_USER_ACTION

const authenticatedUserReducer = (
    state: AuthenticatedUserState = INITIAL_STATE,
    action: ACTION
): AuthenticatedUserState => {
    const { type, payload } = action
    switch (type) {
        case AUTHENTICATED_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: payload.authenticatedUser,
                isAdmin: payload.isAdmin
            }
        case REGISTER_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                isRegistered: payload.isRegistered,
                err: payload.err
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Then, the error is

```
Property 'err' does not exist on type '{ authenticatedUser: any; isAdmin: boolean; } | { isRegistered: boolean; err: any; }'.
  Property 'err' does not exist on type '{ authenticatedUser: any; isAdmin: boolean; }'.
```

Comment: Depending on your typescript version, you might have better luck by not destructuring `action` and instead switching on `action.type` and accessing `action.payload` in the cases of your `switch`. The ability to narrow by a union discriminator that has been destructured into its own variable was only (fairly) recently [added in TS4.6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions)

Comment: The code passes the type-checker on the latest TS release.

Comment: @spender Thanks for your comment. Destructuring was the issue. Instead of using `payload.isAdmin`, `action. payload.isAdmin` works without any issue.

Comment: Voting to reopen because problem is [reproducible using the provided code in versions of TS<4.6](https://tsplay.dev/w2p08m). This version is sufficiently recent that others may also encounter this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you might be using a typescript version < 4.6.

With TS < 4.6, when you destructure a value with a discriminated-union type:

```
const { type, payload } = action
```

you are creating two new variables that have no connection with each other, nor the item from which they were destructured. The compiler is unable to narrow `payload` or `action` by means of checking `type`.

This behaviour changes in [typescript > 4.6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions), so upgrading your typescript version should be considered.

Otherwise, in a pre-TS4.6 world, don't destructure items from your discriminated union for the purpose of type-narrowing/control-flow.

```
switch (action.type) {
    case AUTHENTICATED_USER:
        return {
            ...state,
            user: action.payload.authenticatedUser,
            isAdmin: action.payload.isAdmin
        }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the error by upgrading your TypeScript version. See playground with v4.9.4: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIFcwAsLmAuSAEwFUBnaAZTEJQG8BYAKGVeXQqgH4AuZOEAE9mbZMDKoiAW1C9kAIwD2igDYQBItuIBKEAObjIUCETlLV6kJtbRufAcJZayAUShRFdhcrUanrcUpgPRATAHlMMx9La35MLE9gAC9CYEUQABFCODkHZgBfZmYEdLIwZABJADkKgBUK1AAZAH1KWtRalz4MbFwwfFpSTmpaZABeZEZ-dk4+EHQVFQAaWPE3Dyg+eBUKFenbOYXl1bIgkPDMLbgdiAKiplAjeCQ0ElqACRcq+oBhDpcMs0SJQXNpmqgfvUwlVJrEwIIAA4QPgAcjg8T6A366QA9Kg3p9vhU-p1AcDQSjYgi4IIVIo4EQ+FNRKJ0b08ARiORoPYhLFROJJDIQHxzL4rNNCkwpcxHtBnihtC4AOIVNqgoEgsEQqEw5lseFI1FsnAc1K4pWq9Vg8naSnTam0+mM2HTAVkXQGMrQEyi6J+FlsA78PmSu5MYqlcr4j5fX7-Mla8bINEYs3YkB4glx4kJzUUyMgMrIS1qzo2pMTVPs-qctKZ0vW-N2+6GlA6irQ5Mxwnx0nN8GQzswgA+JZVZY1tsHuvuJSL5RNmM5Jm5UF0RHQSCgyYAFLEyrRumna4M1yNIMnqnUGi02v89qyEBnukPocwAJTHmtY1fDGiXmMAB8rqiPOxZ0MgbZLMgjp0gyyD5MmiAZgeADuwBgAgWDILubYfqBgbIAQFCvLGRIkgCzY8PyRHGGA6BQCAhFEURAB0HGHpAj6sURHA8rBNLwUQbFLumf7QDxvEsoK0igHwcHOmxsnCrRgZSqxJGKhOTa2jRbp0RADFMSx0lsBxbFcRAUlmQEHr6IYPouopDLKfZXpGCYNm2cGLkibYakshpRFEBA8ALGA+m2fRjHMVZsRSvkQA)

Comment: Yes, if I upgrade typescript version to 4.9.4, it does not happen. But that requires many other upgrades, so, it is not preferred. Any other way to fix that?

Comment: @robdev91 "But that requires many other upgrades" what other upgrades? Do you mean code changes? Libraries shouldn't depend on specific minor versions of TS.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev but dev tools such as eslint, or any of its plugins might well do. In, for instance CRA apps, these can be difficult to untangle.